# TikZ-Feynman: Orientating diagram horizontally

Tags: tikz-pgf, feynman, tikz-feynman

I want to make a Feynman diagram using the Tikz-Feynman package, that is aligned horizontally. The command I use looks like:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz-feynman}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,positioning,automata,backgrounds,calc,er,patterns}
\tikzfeynmanset{compat=1.0.0}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\feynmandiagram[horizontal=a to b]{
  i1 -- [fermion] a -- [fermion] i2,
  a -- [photon] b,
  f1 -- [fermion] b -- [fermion] f2,
};
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

According to the documentation, this should look like this:
[image]

but instead it looks like this:

[image]

How do I fix this?

PS: I am using a Sharelatex installation on my own server to compile the document.

Comment: Do you compile with `lualatex`? (If I compile with `lualatex`, I get the desired result, if I compile with `xelatex` I reproduce your result.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was, that my compiler was set to pdfLatex by default. Changing it to LuaLatex makes it work the intended way.