# TikZ-feynman: Changing the angle at a vertex

Tags: feynman, tikz-feynman

I want to draw a feynman diagram for the quark Dyson-Schwinger equation using the Tikz-Feynman package. I have the problem that I can't draw a fermion line that is straight even after a vertex. I have tried the code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-feynman}
\begin{document}
\feynmandiagram[horizontal=b to c] {
   b -- [fermion] c [dot] -- [fermion] d,
   b -- [gluon, half left, edge label=\(q\)] c;
};
\end{document}
```

which produces the output

[image]

What I want is that after the vertex with the dot the fermion line still is angled horizontally.
If I try to align the points b and d horizontally, the output is still wrong:

[image]

Is there a way to automatically fix this or do I have to set the angle manually. If yes, how do I do so?

Edit: I am using the LuaLatex compiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for your MWE. Add `tree layout`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-feynman}
\begin{document}
\feynmandiagram[horizontal=b to c,tree layout] {
   b -- [fermion] c [dot,midway] -- [fermion] d,
   b -- [gluon, half left, edge label=\(q\)] c;
};
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to add that I am using lualatex. Using pdflatex I got some major issues with the feynman diagrams too, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/412260/tikz-feynman-orientating-diagram-horizontally

Comment: @CrustyPeanut Could you please provide a complete [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)?

Comment: I changed the code in my original question to be a MWE. Still the same problem.

Comment: @CrustyPeanut Did you see my update?

Comment: Yes I did, but only now am I able to respond. Thanks a lot, this works just fine!